# is_user_logged_in conflict with wp_redirect

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am trying to hide my custom post type single page from non-logged in users. I used hook `template_redirect` as follows:

```
add_action('template_redirect','hide_single_property');
function hide_single_property()
{
    if( is_singular('property') || is_page('dashboard')):
        if( ! is_user_logged_in() ):
            wp_redirect(get_permalink(103),302);
            exit;
        endif;
    endif;      
}
```

the code above works, but with some problem. Like i try to visit http://example.com/property/abc it redirects to login page. And after login if i try to visit the same post it again redirects back to login page, however works fine with other properties.

It just loads the url before login again :(

Comment: You may have more help for that on the site for WordPress development questions : http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Comment: @mmm no idea ? :(

Comment: sorry, see updated comment below with proper code

Answer (score 0):

if its just the single post you're trying to hide, you can add the following to your sinlge-property.php template file:

```
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) { 
   //your content file 
     get_template_part('content'); 
} 
else {
   //show login page  
     get_template_part('must-login'); 
}
```

Comment: You are correct. But i want to know why it is saving last url and is_user_logged_in why isn't returning true